How to create the fishnet grid in GEE using JS code editor?
I want to create a 10*10 pixel size grid for my AOI.
1 pixel = 10m
var cellSize = 100; // Size of each grid cell 

// Get the bounds of the AOI
var bounds = aoi.geometry().bounds().coordinates().get(0).getInfo();
var xMin = bounds[0][0];
var yMin = bounds[0][1];
var xMax = bounds[2][0];
var yMax = bounds[2][1];

var xCells = Math.ceil((xMax - xMin) / cellSize);
var yCells = Math.ceil((yMax - yMin) / cellSize);

var fishnet = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, xCells - 1).map(function(i) {
    return ee.List.sequence(0, yCells - 1).map(function(j) {
      var xOffset = i * cellSize;
      var yOffset = j * cellSize;
      var xLeft = xMin + xOffset;
      var xRight = xLeft + cellSize;
      var yBottom = yMin + yOffset;
      var yTop = yBottom + cellSize;
      var coordinates = [
        [xLeft, yBottom],
        [xLeft, yTop],
        [xRight, yTop],
        [xRight, yBottom],
        [xLeft, yBottom]
      ];
      return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([coordinates]));
    });
  }).flatten()
);

// Style the fishnet grid to make it visible
var fishnetStyled = fishnet.style({
  color: 'blue',
  width: 1
});

// Add the fishnet grid to the map with styling
Map.addLayer(fishnetStyled, {}, 'Fishnet Grid');

// Center the map on the AOI with an appropriate zoom level
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12);

print("fishnet", fishnet);



You can utilize the coveringGrid function. If you specify the size of the grid cell in meters, ensure that you use a projection scaled in meters.
// Your AOI.
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-106.22693031524932, 45.09711418996627],
  [-105.65838783478057, 45.34281498904193],
  [-106.43841713165557, 45.560538053489246],
  [-106.59222572540557, 45.30032867810689]]
]);

// The grid size in meters.
var scale = 10;

// Creating the fishnet grid.
var grid = aoi.coveringGrid('EPSG:3857', scale);

Map.centerObject(aoi);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'AOI');
Map.addLayer(grid, {}, 'Grid');

